# Database or flat file storage for Node packages

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a simple node package, and I want to keep user editable data somewhere.

What I need to store is extremely simple, and a flat file would work too. Here's a representation of example data in JSON:

```
{ 
  "projects": [
    {
      "name": "foo",
      "dir": "C:/bar"
    },
    {
      "name": "baz",
      "dir": "D:/foobaz"
    }
  ]
}
```

As far as I know, common packages I use (express, meteor, gulp) do not store data in such way, at most they have configuration files.

Using [flat-file-db](https://www.npmjs.org/package/flat-file-db) (for example) will make the technical part easy, but I'm wondering what are the accepted norms on how to handle such storage, and how to go about that, *i.e*, what kind of naming (`data.js` in `./lib/` folder or in `./db/`?) and location (user directory or package install location?)

Comment: Re accepted norms for storage: It depends on your requirements. It seems like in your case the file system would be fine. For larger amounts of data / data being reconfigured (ie joined with other data) you'd probably want a database

Comment: @ControlAltDel Thanks! Though what kind of naming and location of the data is acceptable? Edited my question to reflect that.